# State of a card game in Clojure

Tags: clojure, game-engine, state

I'm relatively new to clojure, but have a grasp of the major functional concepts. Something I'm really struggling with is state.

I'm writing a simple card game app, it has come to the point where I'm writing the game engine. So the concept of state has slapped me in the face very quickly.

I need keep track of lots of things pertinent to the game:

- The state of the deck
- The state of the points
- Who was dealer
- ... ect

I've done reading into how state is used in clojure, Refs, Agents, Atoms, and thread local vars. But none of them seem like the right option for what i'm doing.

So my actual question: What clojure construct do I use to maintain state of a single-threaded game engine in clojure?

Answer (score 8):

A general principle of functional programming is that you can make your code more general by replacing global state with an added input arg and output arg for each function accessing state.

In this case, that would mean providing a `game` arg to each round of play, and having each round of play return a new `game` to be used going forward. There are a few advantages to this. There is no mutation, so there is no need to manage and coordinate mutation. Your tests can consist of running one turn of the round of play function. If you need AI, it can trivially run many branching turns of the game on a breadth-first basis to test likely outcomes without interfering with the state of the actual game.

A rough sketch of what this could look like:

```
(def make-game
  [players]
  (let [[draw & deck] (shuffle cards)]
  {:draw draw
   :deck deck
   :points (zipmap players (repeat 0))
   :dealer (first players)})

(defn run-round
  [game]
  (let [points (update-points (:draw game) (:points game))
        [draw & deck] (:deck game)]
    (assoc game :deck deck :draw draw :points points)))

(defn winner?
  [game]
  (some #(> (val %) 42) (:points game)))

(defn -main
  (let [gameplay (take-while #(not (winner? %))
                             (iterate run-round (make-game)))]
    (:points (run-round (last gameplay)))))
```

This is of course a very trivial game where the points of each player are derived from the card drawn. The next card will be drawn from the shuffled deck on each turn until we have a total score indicating a winner.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the state of this game has several components, the deck, points, dealer, etc. so you can choose to put all of this into a single map and store that in one of the uncoordinated mutable data types (`atom`, `agent`, `var`) or store them separately and use the coordinated mutable data type, the `ref`. Since you say the game is single threaded then it may be slightly easier to go the uncoordinated route to save typing the word `dosync` a few times, though it won't be a big difference in effort either way.

```
(def state-of-game (atom {:deck ...
                          :points
                          :dealer}))
```